# DioError [DioErrorType.connectTimeout]: Connecting timed out api works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt work

Tags: flutter, timeout, dio

when i call my api from android or ios simulator it works fine but with pysciall device after few api calls it starts giving `DioError [DioErrorType.connectTimeout]:` Connecting timed out [0ms]
flutter: Source stack: `DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:473:35)`
flutter: #1      `DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:468:12)`
flutter: #2      DioMixin.post (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:91:12)
i have tried multiple solutions but i have failed to find the exact solution

i have checked api and its ssl everything is fine it evens works with login, sign up show data but when i go to different screens sometimes it works sometimes it gives error
have also tried setting timeout value using options

Answer (score 0):

Test the api with Postman. Sometimes the backend could take lot of time processing the request leading to this result.

You can increase timeout duration in dio with `BaseOptions` as well.

Comment: its working fine with android devices, simulator, postman just gives error with ios physical device

Comment: is your server http or https?

Comment: that too sometimes after few api calls

Comment: its https as i mentioned earlier it works fine with every other platform

Comment: looks like your backend requires some improvements.

Comment: like the api side or my code side? what puzzles me is that it works with android and ios simulator

Comment: [DioErrorType.other]: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake
sometime i get this error